# PhoneGAP how to upload to googleplay and apple store

Tags: cordova

I went through the link below. It shows how to create a project using PhoneGAP in Android environment, but it does not show

1. how to upload the solution to android market.
2. how to convert the solution to IOS and how to upload it on to apple apps store.

Could anyone please direct me to the right tutorials to learn above?

http://tboxmy.blogspot.com.au/2013/08/creating-android-app-with-phonegap-and.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/)** for a hassle free work. you just need to provide the html, css and js files and it will convert it into all possible app formats, android, wp8, ios, bada, tizen, etc.

As for your question is concrned, you need the finished .apk file (for android) and .ipa file (for iOS) to publish.

For more step by step knowledge on publishing to android/google play store, you should [consider reading this](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html)

for iOS, the guidelines are pretty strict for all apps, even native, heard that even they dont allow most of the phonegap based apps. However, you can consider [reading these guidelines before publishing](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html)

You need a publisher account at both the places, which charge nominal fee for sign ups.

Comment: thats all on your wish. just create a mobile friendly website. You'll ideally have these three components. You'll either need a github repository or an adobe id to go forward with the phonegap build. All you'll need to do is provide the url for the repository wherever you have uploaded these files and the website will be processed and modified to an app (in the layman language). Choice of IDE is on you. be it Dreamweaver or just notepad

Comment: Thanks, what I still don't understand is how database connection works on PhoneGAP. let say I develop a website like gumtree.com using these three components and the website links to a database and it hosted on a third party server. if put the web url to phoneGAP I hope it will create apps code  for android, ios etc for me. but I am not sure about database connection. Does the phoneGAP create database for each kind of app?

Comment: No, for that you need some server side scripting too. You can make the similar looking php/asp/jsp pages on some hosting, and call those pages from inside your static index.html page which you turn into an apk file using phonegap. remaining everything will be called on the server from the app, including database and connection and you get everything running on the phone. I guess I made my point clear. If yes then kindly accept my answer, as I'm looking to increase my repo on stackoverflow :)